# Vim error: can't open file /tmp/.* when run some commands need temporary files

Tags: vim

Gentoo, vim version 7.3.762

Problem:
**ONLY** happened when the vim instance has been ran for a long time (like 2 hours). Then I ran some commands which require temporary files like `:Gstatus` in plugin `fugitive`, I will get an error:

```
can't open file /tmp/RANDOM_NAME
```

I can't figure out what the reason caused this. Is it has anything to do with the auto-clean strategy of the operating system?
Because I encountered this problem not only when running the `fugitive` commands, but also the function below:

```
" Use ranger as vim's file chooser
fun! RangerChooser()
    silent !ranger --choosefile=/tmp/chosenfile $([ -z '%' ] && echo -n . || dirname %)
    if filereadable('/tmp/chosenfile')
        exec 'edit ' . system('cat /tmp/chosenfile')
        call system('rm /tmp/chosenfile')
    endif
    redraw!
endfun
```

Comment: Maybe /tmp is a virtual filesystem that fills up?

Comment: I've encountered this, too. It seems to be some kind of wonky state in the vim session. It always goes away with a vim restart, and doesn't affect other vim sessions running at the same time. It's something wrong with `system()` itself. I can reproduce the errors with `:echo system('ls')` when it happens.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ran into this problem because I had recently changed my shell from `fish` to `bash`. Changing my shell in my `vimrc` fixed the problem:

`set shell=/bin/bash`

Comment: I was seeing an error in vim because an extension couldn't open up tmp files. Setting the shell as mentioned in this answer fixed it for me. The extension that caused this problem for me is called airline and the error I saw was: `Error detected while processing function airline#extensions#branch#get_head[1]`... It's all resolved now though. Just mentioning it here in case anyone else is searching for it. Thanks!

Comment: You save my day. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't expect this to work for windows too, but it does! Thanks :)

Comment: THANKS, I was trying to solve this problem for hours now

Comment: I was using cmd to run nvim, but had set shell to gitbash, once I changed set shell back to cmd, the error went away. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread. Still posting in case it helps someone.

I recently encountered this error on my system. The filename was of the form "/tmp// Turns out, the /tmp/ directory had been cleaned after I had launched my vim instance, which had been running for a couple of days straight.

A quick `mkdir /tmp/<random-dir-name>` fixed the issue without having to restart vim.

Comment: 7 years later and "mkdir" fixes it for me using vim on windows :)

Answer (score 2):

I know the fugutive plugin makes use of tempname() internal vim function.  This function returns a filepath of a unique filename that is in a directory in /tmp on Unix style systems.  This error can happen if the directory is no longer there.  I do not know for sure this is what you are running into but it is something to check.

If you type `:echo isdirectory(fnamemodify(tempname(), ":p:h"))` and is returns 0, see if `:call mkdir(fnamemodify(tempname(), ":p:h"))` causes the problem to go away.

Comment: Sadly I did't see this problem happened again recently~ (well i've upgraded my linux kernel from 3.8 to 3.10.7). I was wondering if there is any possibility that OS clean the tempfile while vim was still using it.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't expect it to help, but `:call mkdir(fnamemodify(tempname(), ":p:h"))` fixes the problem. Looks like you can also get vim into this broken state by deleting a tmp path out from under vim with `:call system('rm -rf ' . fnamemodify(tempname(), ':p:h'))`.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your vimrc file，and create folder .tmp in your home foler

```
let $TMPDIR = $HOME."/tmp"
```